# Define namespace scope function

Tags: c++, linker, namespaces

I want to define public function in namespace scope (not in Class - this works)
Basically I want use it like for example the:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds(16)
```

I've tried many setups but here is the recent one:

#### TimeX.h

```
#ifndef TIMEX_H
#define TIMEX_H

namespace timee{

    int now(int z);

}

#endif
```

#### TimeX.cpp

```
#include <chrono>
#include "TimeX.h"
using namespace timee;

int now(int z){return 4;}
```

#### Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TimeX.h"

using namespace timee;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    long c = now(2);
    std::cout << "c" << c <<std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

And this gives me following error:

> Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl timee::now(int)" (?now@timee@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _SDL_main

What is the problem with this? It's confusing. Why linker tells me that this is referenced in `_SDL_main`? I use SDL library but what it has to do with my function?

#### Second problem related with this code.

And also one additional question (if it is not easy to answer I would start new  topic). I'm using `timee` for namespace name because I've had an error telling that `time` name is used somewhere already [Error C2757](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyk2d912.aspx). I guess it is probably nested somewhere. How can I find out where it is used and is it possible to use the name anyway? I can't imagine how compiler have a problem in figuring out what I want to use.

Comment: You defined a function `now` when you meant to define a function `timee::now`. The `using namespace timee;` does not put all definitions into `timee`.

Comment: yup, it works. Now if yo could briefly explain why... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the function like

```
int timee::now(int z){return 4;}
```

Or you could write for example this way

```
#include <chrono>
#include "TimeX.h"

namespace timee
{
    int now(int z){return 4;}
}
```

Otherwise in the cpp module there is declared (and defined) another function with the same name in the global namespace

```
#include <chrono>
#include "TimeX.h"
using namespace timee;

int now(int z){return 4;}
```

That is these two definitions

```
int timee::now(int z){return 4;} 
int now(int z){return 4;}
```

define different functions. The first one declares (and defines) the function in the namespace `timee` while the second one declares (and defines) another function with the same name in the global namespace.

As for the name `time` then it is defined in the global namespace and corresponds to the C standard function `time`. For example the header `<chrono>` can in turn include the header `<time.h>` where the name `time` is declared.

Comment: You mean [this function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/?kw=time) ? I'm confused, I don't include `<time.h>`  how does it get into my code? I would probably start another question about it...

Comment: I didn't accept the answer because I'm hoping someone explain the linker error message...

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I think that it is this function. The header can be included indirectly through inclusion of other headers. For example it can be included by the header <chrono>.

Comment: So I believe there is no workaround on this? It's still bizarre to me - the linker can figure out two function with the same name but with different parameters but it cannot distinct function and namespace with the same name. Even more bizarre is why we have global functions with such common names in standard library (although it's not C exclusive).

Comment: @PawełAudionysos What workaround are you speaking about? The name of a namespace must be unique.

Comment: I mean I guess there is no workaround but on the other hand it don't see to be much complicated to figure out if you are referring to namespace or function in your code (If you would be able to have the two with the same name)

Comment: Should I accept your answer and start new question about deciphering `error LNK2019` message?

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I pointed out in my answer why the error occurs.

Comment: Yes, but the question was also why error message says `int __cdecl timee::now(int)` is allegedly referenced in `_SDL_main`

Comment: @PawełAudionysos The function is not defined. SO the compiler issues an error. You have to define the function.

Comment: Jesus! I have get this already, I had this code working 11h ago. Don't get me wrong. I don't demand the answer from you. It's fine if you don't know it but I'm really curious about the message and hope maybe someone could add something to the topic....

Comment: @PawełAudionysos It seems that SDL provides its own entry point.